# Software for Android App Documentation

Tags: android, web-development, documentation-generator

I am doing documentation of my Android app. I want to create a documentation of my product like Facebook does in their docs. I am looking for a software which can help me to document my product for my users so they can easily understand how it works and they can copy code from my documentation to their Android application as I am developing a SaaS product. Currently I am making it in Java, and soon we will shift to Kotlin.